# How to create a numpy ndarray with bool elements?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array `boo_array` with bool elements. Following is how I generated it

```
> a = np.ndarray([2, 1])
> boo_array = a>1

> print(boo_array)
[[False]
 [False]]
```

I check the type of elements

```
> print(type(boo_array[0]))
> print(type(boo_array[0][0]))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.bool_'>
```

I see that the first element `[False]` is an `numpy.ndarray`. So, I try to create `my_boo_array` with the following code:

```
> my_boo_arr = np.ndarray(boo_array[0][0]) # Which should generate an ndarray '[False]'
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Why is this error thrown when I manually create it, but allows to generate a similar array shown above `boo_array[0]`

Comment: Don't use `np.ndarray` (unless you really need it's specific functionality).  `np.array` is the normal tool for making an array from a list.

Comment: i tried np.array. But the resulting array does not allow me to iterate. 
```boo_elem = np.array(False)
for i in range(0,1):
    print(boo_elem[i])``` --> IndexError: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed. 
 Where as  boo_array[0] does allow me to ```for i in range(0,1):
    print(boo_array[0][i])```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `boo_array[0][0]` is not an array.  It is a single value.  When `np.ndarray` is presented with a single (non-list, non-array) value, it assumes that it is the size of the array it is supposed to create.

`boo_array[0]` is a one-dimensional array.  `np.ndarray` will convert that to an array, which is a no-op.

Comment: So are you saying there is no way I can create that np.ndarray ```[False]``` i.e ```boo_array[0]`` manually ?

Comment: Of course you can.  You just need to make it a list.  If you want a 1x1 array that contains the first element of `boo_array`, then you need `np.ndarray( [boo_array[0][0]] )`.  Since `boo_array[0]` achieves the same goal, I'm not sure why you would want to.

Comment: 1. No, It throws error ```TypeError: an integer is required```  Please try it out.
2. Reason -> I want to make a ```'numpy.bool_'``` object into an iterable format so that the later code can pick it up.

Comment: Then use `np.array`, not `np.ndarray`.  `np.array([False])` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

`ndarray([2,1])` creates a (2,1) shape array with float dtype.  If you read the docs, you'll see described as a low-level array creator.  Usually we use `np.array`, or `np.zeros` (and a few others).

For an example a (2,1) shape with bool dtype, and all False values:

```
In [202]: a = np.zeros((2,1), dtype=bool)    
In [203]: a
Out[203]: 
array([[False],
       [False]])
```

We can select a "row" from that with:

```
In [204]: a[0]
Out[204]: array([False])
```

That has (1,) shape, the 2nd dimension of `a`.  Indexing both row and column:

```
In [205]: a[0,0]
Out[205]: False
```

That's  a scalar value.  For integer indexing `a[0][0]` does the same thing.  That's not an array.  It's type is `numpy.bool_`, which does have some array like qualities, including a shape `()` (0d).

We can make an array from that with:

```
In [206]: np.array(a[0,0])
Out[206]: array(False)
```

This too has shape () (no brackets).  `np.ndarray` does not work here because the first argument is supposed to be "shape".  Use `np.array` when you want to make an array from values.

Making a (2,) shape array with 2 False values:

```
In [207]: np.array([False, False])
Out[207]: array([False, False])

In [208]: np.array([[False], [True]])  # (2,1) shape
Out[208]: 
array([[False],
       [ True]])

In [215]: a.shape
Out[215]: (2, 1)
```

`a` with 2dim, can be indexed with `a[0]` or `a[0,0]`.

A 1d array can only be indexed with one integer:

```
In [216]: b = np.array([False])    
In [217]: b.shape
Out[217]: (1,)    
In [218]: b[0]
Out[218]: False
```

A 0d array cannot be indexed with a number (or iterated):

```
In [219]: b = np.array(False)
In [220]: b.shape
Out[220]: ()
In [221]: b[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [221], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 b[0]

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed
```

It can be indexed with an empty tuple - with 0 indices:

```
In [222]: b[()]
Out[222]: False
```